# jquery - this.each isn't executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, coffeescript

I am trying to learn CoffeeScript by creating a little plugin for jQuery that will move a div tag to keep it on the screen. For some reason I can't get the 'return this.each' to run correctly. I have tried just the basic structure from the jQuery Plugin Authoring page but that still wouldn't work. Is there something special that I have to do to get this to work?

I am running this script on Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.2 with the coffee-rails (3.2.1) and jquery-rails (2.0.1) gems.

**CoffeeScript**

```
$ = jQuery

defaults =
  paddingTop: 10


$.fn.fixedTop = (options) ->
    settings = $.extend defaults, options
    this.each () ->
      beginPoint = this.offset().top - settings.paddingTop
      $(window).scroll () ->
        scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()
        if beginPoint < scrollTop
          $(this).css 'marginTop', (scrollTop-beginPoint)+settings.paddingTop
```

**Generated JS**

```
(function() {
  var $, defaults;
  $ = jQuery;
  defaults = {
    paddingTop: 10
  };
  $.fn.fixedTop = function(options) {
    var settings;
    settings = $.extend(defaults, options);
    return this.each(function() {
      var beginPoint;
      beginPoint = this.offset().top - settings.paddingTop;
      return $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrollTop;
        scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (beginPoint < scrollTop) {
          return $(this).css('marginTop', (scrollTop - beginPoint) + settings.paddingTop);
        }
      });
    });
  };
}).call(this);
```

Comment: the inner returns seem to be redundant there. erase them, try again and tell me what happens.

Comment: they are automatically generated by coffeescript, i tried removing the returns and the code did not run. i placed break points on either side of the return this.each and the first one was triggered but the second  was not.

Comment: @elclanrs You already answered your question: less code. And it is not harder to read. People who code in Python or Ruby actually find it more natural.

Comment: Yeah I guess it feels more natural, I mean it's the default in Rails... I just need my curly braces! I can't stand the "read as in English" code.

Comment: You can prevent CoffeeScript from returning the result of the last expression by inserting an explicit `return` as the last line of your function. If you could post the HTML that you are working with it will make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: I would expect each to be a function of `$(this)` and not _this_. So $.each could perhaps be a better idea

Comment: I mean, keep the first return, replace this.each with $(this).each, remove the two returns inside it. They are redundant.

Comment: @tpaksu: Everything is an expression in CoffeeScript, that's where all the extra `return`s come from: the CS to JS compiler adds them. The `return this.each(...)` is standard practice in jQuery plugins, `this` will already be jQuery-ified in that context so saying `$(this).each` is pointless.

Comment: Yea I know that, but you can't trust a generator each time right? And yes I remembered that wrong because I use a different approach for jQuery plugins :) But tell me, what does `return $(elem).event()` mean? it returns $(elem) doesn't it? and inner return does the same thing too? Ok, I get it, its just for the chainability. no other function right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have various problems here.

We'll start by adding some line numbers:

```
1  $.fn.fixedTop = (options) ->
2    settings = $.extend defaults, options
3    this.each () ->
4      beginPoint = this.offset().top - settings.paddingTop
5      $(window).scroll () ->
6        scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()
7        if beginPoint < scrollTop
8          $(this).css 'marginTop', (scrollTop-beginPoint)+settings.paddingTop
```

At line 4, `this` is not a jQuery object that supports the [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) method, it is just a plain old DOM object; you need to use `$(this)` (or, since we're in CoffeeScript land, `$(@)`).

You have another context problem at line 8: `this` is not the same `this` you had up at line 4, this `this` is `window` because the scroll event is being triggered on `window`. You can solve this by caching a reference to the appropriate object:

```
$el = $(@)
#...
$(window).scroll () ->
    # Use $el rather than $(@) in here
```

or by using a [fat arrow](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow) to bind the `$(window).scroll` callback to the context you want:

```
$(window).scroll () =>
```

You should also use `@` instead of `this` in CoffeeScript.

When we fix those problems we have this:

```
$.fn.fixedTop = (options) ->
  settings = $.extend defaults, options
  @each () ->
    $el = $(@)
    beginPoint = $el.offset().top - settings.paddingTop 
    $(window).scroll () -> 
      scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop() 
      if beginPoint < scrollTop 
        $el.css 'marginTop', (scrollTop - beginPoint) + settings.paddingTop
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/cmBYD/

Or this:

```
$.fn.fixedTop = (options) ->
  settings = $.extend defaults, options
  @each () ->
    beginPoint = $(@).offset().top - settings.paddingTop 
    $(window).scroll () => 
      scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop() 
      if beginPoint < scrollTop 
        $(@).css 'marginTop', (scrollTop - beginPoint) + settings.paddingTop
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/JCbJj/

You'll see that you still have some bugs but you should be able to fix those now that you have something that actually runs. You probably want to keep your JavaScript console open while developing and debugging (Java|Coffee)Script too.

The main lesson here is (ahem) this: every time you refer to `this` in JavaScript or `@` in CoffeeScript, double check that your code is running in the right context and triple check if there are callback functions involved.